# Python - exec(self.x=1) works but exec(x=1) doesn't in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, exec

The title should speak for itself. Here's an example:

```
class Example():
    def function(self):
        exec("self.a = 'Hello'")
        exec("b = 'World'")
        print(self.a)
        print(b)
```

Then when I call the function `Example()function()` it returns:

`Hello
 (...)
 NameError: name 'b' is not defined`

Could someone explain why **b** is not defined but **self.a** is?

Comment: Because the local namespace will not be affected by `exec`

Comment: `locals()["a"]` will give you `"World"`.

Comment: Read the note at the bottom of the [exec doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

Comment: @anonymoose yes, and yet, the local namespace is not affected.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My intent was not to challenge your post. Sorry it came off that way. I was just trying to suggest a way for the OP to achieve his desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you real much for the answers. I’ll surely read into it :p